# How can I get each implementation into one list so that I have access to each string

Tags: python, list, append

```
for i in range(0,len(new)):
    m = re.search(r"core-\b(\d+)", new[i])
    if (m):
        m_1 = []
        m_1.append(m.group(1))
        print(m_1)
```

The implementation I have above places each iteration in its own list

Answer (score 1):

The scope of m_1 is within the search done on each element of the list. It should be outside the scope of the loop if you want to store

```py
import re


m_1 = []
for i in range(0,len(new)):
    m = re.search(r"core-\b(\d+)", new[i])
    if (m):
        m_1.append(m.group(1))
        print(m_1)
```

Comment: This code out puts four list ['01'],[01,01],[01,01,02],[01,01,02,02] I would only like to access the elements in the last one

Comment: @KierraHoward it will output the entire list at each step of the search. so all 4 lists outputted are the same list at different steps. the last output is the list at the end of the loop. if you want to do something with it, do it after the loop ends

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .extend() list function instead of .append(). Using extend() will mean that your final list m_1 will be one list of elements, while append() results in a list of lists.